# Integrating FFMPEG using cmake: dlopen failed: library "libavutil.so.56" not found

Tags: android, ffmpeg, cmake, android-ndk, linker

This question is a subsequent thread following this [other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409947/integrating-ffmpeg-using-cmake-undefined-reference-when-linking-libraries).

After finally managing to successfully building the apk file using gradle and cmake to integrate FFMPEG into an Android project I am facing a new exception which is thrown when calling `System.loadLibrary`.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libavutil.so.56" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at com.hmomeni.canto.activities.EditActivity.<init>(EditActivity.kt:26)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is the part of code which is causing the error:

```
class EditActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    init {
        System.loadLibrary("Canto")
    }
...
}
```

I tried moving the `.so` files inside the `PROJECT/app/jniLibs` and then adding the following line to `build.gradle` file to no avail.

```
sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['./jniLibs/']
```

Comment: what is your directory content inside `/jniLibs/` ?

Comment: @shizhen, sorry I'm replying this late. It's `app/jniLibs/ffmpeg/{ANDROID_ABI}/lib`.

Comment: Your jniLibs.srcDirs should include the path till the level of directory **ffmpeg** and remove **/lib**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure your **jniLibs.srcDirs** as below:

```
sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['./jniLibs/']
```

Then your path `app/jniLibs/ffmpeg/{ANDROID_ABI}/lib` is not correct and your `.so` files won't be found and packaged by your build system.

Try to make your **jniLibs** structure be as below:

```
jniLibs
│   ├── x86
│   ├── x86_64
│   ├── arm64-v8a
│   ├── armeabi-v7a
```

Dont add `lib` behind `{ANDROID_ABI}/`.

---

**---Edit---**

> And after manually loading the libraries using System.loadLibrary I encountered a new error which indicates that libavutil has text relocations and it seems that for API-23 and above it is not permitted.

Maybe you should try to build your ffmpeg with option `--disable-asm` and `-fPIC` to have a binary without text relocation. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39965908/8034839, but it looks there still some issue with NEON.

Another discussion for your information: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50207091/8034839

Comment: I changed the directory structure to `app/jniLibs/{ANDROID_ABI}/libavutil.so.56` but I'm still getting the same result. The library can not be found.

Comment: Remove “.56” from your lib name

Comment: Actually all versions of the file names are present in the directory. Check this image to see for yourself. https://imgur.com/a/j7s6Eka

Comment: Have you analyzed your apk? Try to check whether your .so are packaged inside. I am using mobile, please forgive my brievity of reply.

Comment: Probably you need to explicitly load all the.so from init{} just like “Canto”

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to help me. I checked the apk and realized that the `.so` files are present in it.

Comment: And after manually loading the libraries using `System.loadLibrary` I encountered a new error which indicates that `libavutil has text relocations` and it seems that for API-23 and above it is not permitted.

Comment: Then, I think the ffmpeg lib you compiled could not be dlopen by Android, meaning that it’s not compatible and cause unsatisfied link errors