# Adding FFmpeg library as dependency in Visual studio project to get rid of LNK2019 error

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, dependencies

While compiling a project on Microsoft visual studio (to generate dll), I am getting the following linking errors (LNK2019)

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol av_strerror referenced in function "private: void __cdecl DecoderFFmpeg::printErrorMsg(int)" (?printErrorMsg@DecoderFFmpeg@@AEAAXH@Z)

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels referenced in function "private: int __cdecl DecoderFFmpeg::initSwrContext(void)"*

several other functions like av_dict_set, av_dict_free, avcodec_decode2 which is related to the ffmpeg libraries. **Can anyone please tell me how to properly add "ffmpeg" as dependenciesto this project and link it properly?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FFMPEG Link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742626/ffmpeg-link-error)